# HP OfficeJet 4655 prints B/W only

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, printer

HP printer (HP OfficeJet 4655) under Ubuntu 16.04 has started printing B/W only. No color.
-Prints test page ok, except B/W only.

-Copies in color so ink cartridges and mechanism are OK.

-Reinstalled hplp-3-17-11 (current version of printer controller)

-verified correct print driver was selected during HPLP install.

-Tried printer on another computer and it prints in color OK.

-localhost:631 displays CUPS 2.1.3 page, but admin page and others are NOT FOUND.

Here are the directories of cups and ppd

cups>>  ls

classes.conf  classes.conf.O  cups-browsed.conf  cupsd.conf  cups-files.conf  interfaces  ppd  printers.conf  printers.conf.O  raw.convs  raw.types  snmp.conf  ssl  subscriptions.conf  subscriptions.conf.O

cups>>

ppd>>  ls

K-BEPSON-Stylus-NX330.ppd  K-BEPSON-Stylus-NX330.ppd.O  OfficeJet_4650_fax.ppd  OfficeJet_4650.ppd

ppd>>

The offending printer is the OfficeJet 4650.

The Epson listed is not at my current location and it functioned as expected the last time I tried it (4 months ago)

So what is causing the CUPS 2.3.1 NOT FOUND errors mentioned above???

Comment: Have you installed the printer on a different computer and tried printing color?

Comment: No. I will see if I can find another computer. Good suggestion.

Comment: Yes, the printer functions normally (prints in color) on another computer.

Comment: Tried printing again on the original computer (one with problem) and got the following error:  There was an error during the CUPS operation: 'No such file or directory'.

Comment: So the issue is with the software/driver on the original computer. Also, please add any additional information to the original question by using the Edit button. This allows the question to be complete. Comments aren't expected to stick around forever, so all pertinent information is best added to the original question.